# How do I get week number automatically into next cell if I enter Date?

Tags: excel-2010

I have created macro button for `DATE` as shown below:

```
Sub asdf()
ActiveCell.Value = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yy")
End Sub
```

I would like to add relevant week number automatically into next cell if I enter the `DATE` into first cell. Is it possible? Could anyone help for this?

Comment: More explanation needed.  Do you want this to happen when you hit the button, or just when you type in a date?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, putting the week number (weeks starting with Sundays) one cell to the right:

```
Sub asdf()
    ActiveCell.Value = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yy")
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = Application.WeekNum(ActiveCell, 1)
End Sub
```